# Can you read a recording while it's being written?

Tags: agora.io

For cloud or server recording, is it possible to read/stream the recording file while it's being written? For example, let's say an online class is from 10-11am, but a student wants to watch from 1030-1130am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to stream the recorded content while the cloud recording service is still recording.

Agora's cloud recording writes files in 15sec chunks and saves them to your cloud bucket (s3, Ali Cloud, etc) as `.ts` files, so you can stream the `.ts` files to the user who joined later.

> Its worth noting that the only files that have been written can be streamed. For example if the cloud recording started 10sec ago, the late user would not be able to stream the first chunk of the call until the 15sec mark when the file has been written.